# Join rows in 2D array on common values

Tags: javascript

Given the following 2D array:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3], [5, 6], [6, 3], [6, 5]]
```

I want to condense the multidimensional array into rows of common values like such:

```
[[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
var indicesArr = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3], [5, 6], [6, 3], [6, 5]];
console.log("Untransformed 2D array: " + JSON.stringify(indicesArr));
var res = [];
for (var idx = 0; idx < indicesArr.length; idx++) {
     for (var cnt = 0; cnt < indicesArr.length; cnt++) {
        if (idx != cnt) {
           if (compareArrays(indicesArr[idx], indicesArr[cnt])) {
              var arr = indicesArr[idx].filter(v => indicesArr[cnt].indexOf(v) > -1);
              res.push(arr);
           }
        }
     }
}
console.log("Rearranged to same order 2D array: " + JSON.stringify(res));
var uniqueRes = multiDimensionalUnique(res);
console.log("Unique 2D array: " + JSON.stringify(uniqueRes));

function compareArrays(arr1, arr2){
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
  arr1.sort();
  arr2.sort();
  for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function multiDimensionalUnique(arr) {
    var uniques = [];
    var itemsFound = {};
    for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
        if(itemsFound[stringified]) { continue; }
        uniques.push(arr[i]);
        itemsFound[stringified] = true;
    }
    return uniques;
}
```

As you can see, I am awful close, as I was able to get my latest 2D array to this format:

```
[[1,2],[1,4],[2,4],[3,5],[3,6],[5,6]]
```

To give some more context into what exactly I'm looking to find as common between each row, see this example. If you have a simple 2D array of `[ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] ]`, it should return an empty 2D array. That's because there are less than three pairs of values appearing at least twice. With m = minimum pairs and n = number of columns per row, you get 3 from m = n + 1 = 2 + 1. If you were to have `[ [1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 4] ]`, however, it would return `[ [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]`, since each value was able to be paired with another and shared a common value each time. This is the best I can do to explain it.

Comment: It's not clear which values are common and why.

Comment: @Kosh Based on looking at my array at the bottom of the question, you'll see. The tough part is explaining the commonalities.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz If you're referring to forming sets based on only common (not disjoint) values, then yes.

Comment: If you have the example you demonstrated, it should return an empty 2D array. That's because there are less than three pairs of values appearing at least twice. With m = minimum pairs and n = number of columns per row, you get 3 from m = n + 1 = 2 + 1. If you were to have `[ [1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 4] ]`, however, it would return `[ [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]`, since each value was able to be paired with another and shared a common one each time.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Actually, the arrays in my program are variable length by row, so cardinality is not always 2. For this example, however, I am using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the parts in new arrays with common values.

```js
const
    data = [[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 1], [4, 2], [5, 3], [5, 6], [6, 3], [6, 5]],
    result = data.reduce((r, a) => {
        const
            [left, temp] = r.reduce((t, b) => {
                t[+b.some(v => a.includes(v))].push(b);
                return t;
            }, [[], [...a]])

        return [...left, Array.from(new Set(temp.flat())).sort((a, b) => a - b)];
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```